# Extra text is written to file c#

Tags: c#, file, stream, buffer

I am currently trying to find the most efficient way to read text and re-write it into a text file. When I do so, (with a file of 223 KB), I get a result of a 224KB file, appending a few extra sentences to the original file. (These few extra sentences seem to be grabbed from the middle of the file). I cannot seem to find what the problem is. The following is the code I am using:

```
        while(...)
        {
            writeStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);

            if (read == 0)
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Not related but `.Close()` calls `.Flush()` so you could save yourself some code.

Comment: @test Don't you still see the answer? You always write `array.Length` bytes but at the last iteration only some part of `array` is filled with real data. So you should write only bytes you read (count is in `read` variable)

Comment: I also had to refresh the 'array' buffer as the last operation of my while loop since after this question, I had to modify what I read and I couldn't use the 'read' as the 3rd parameter :/

Comment: @test Funny that I have written millions of such codes and always could be able to use the returned value from `read` and never need a `refresh`.

Comment: once I read the text I was passing it to method to remove some punctuation; so I placed my new bytes in a new array, and if I used 'read' as the third parameter, I would get an argument out of bounds exception since read would be larger than newArray.Length. Thus I passed newArray.Length as my parameter, This worked for small files, and I thought it would work for larger files (128MB) but still, even with clearing the array within the while loop, some text would not be read at the end!!! I have never figured this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the third parameter of the 'write' method is incorrect. replace it with read and it should work

Answer (score 8):

It should be:

```
writeStream.Write(array, 0, read );
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this out immediately